# Calculate frequency of occurrence in an array using R

Tags: r

I have an array

```
a <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,7,7,7,7)
```

I would like to use some command that would tell me which is the most frequent number in the array?

is there a simple command for this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `table()` function is sufficient for this, and particularly useful if your data have more than one *mode*.

Consider the following options, all related to `table()` and `max()`.

---

```
# Your vector
a = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,7,7,7,7)

# Basic frequency table
table(a)
# a
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
# 5 1 1 1 5 1 4 

# Only gives me the value for highest frequency
# Doesn't tell me which number that is though
max(table(a))
# [1] 5

# Gives me a logical vector, which might be useful
# but not what you're asking for in this question
table(a) == max(table(a))
# a
#    1     2     3     4     5     6     7 
# TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE 

# This is probably more like what you're looking for
which(table(a) == max(table(a)))
# 1 5 
# 1 5 

# Or, maybe this
names(which(table(a) == max(table(a))))
# [1] "1" "5"
```

As indicated in the comments, in some cases you might want to see the two or three most commonly occurring values, in which case `sort()` is useful:

```
sort(table(a))
# a
# 2 3 4 6 7 1 5 
# 1 1 1 1 4 5 5
```

You can also set a threshold for which values to return in your table. For instance, if you wanted to return only those numbers which occurred more than once:

```
sort(table(a)[table(a) > 1])
# a
# 7 1 5 
# 4 5 5
```

Comment: The `which.max` function could simplify the above a bit (but the long version given here is great for understanding).

Comment: @GregSnow, that was the basic idea behind the extended version. As for use of `which.max`, doesn't that return only the *first* matching value. That is, if one were to use `names(which.max(table(a)))`, I think (can't check right now) they would only get `"1"` as the answer. Or did you have something else in mind that can be edited into the answer above?

Comment: you are correct that `which.max` only returns the 1st match.  The chance of having more than 1 value equalling the max decreases with the number of possible values and size of the vector, so it is still reasonable in some cases, but yours is the more general solution.  I prefer looking at the whole table (like you start with) because if the max is 100 and there is another value that has 99 then that is still very interesting but the automated "mode" procedures will not show that.

Comment: @GregSnow,Thanks for your comments, and good point about sometimes being interested in other values that might be close in frequency to the mode. I edited my answer to include a suggestion to use `sort(table(a))` so that the most frequently occurring values are "clumped" together. My general suggestion in these types of analysis (with larger datasets, of course) is to first plot either a stripchart, stem-and-leaf plot, histogram, or density plot to get an "overview" of the data distribution before jumping into different measures of central tendency.

Answer (score 5):

Use `table()` function:

```
## Your vector:
a <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,7,7,7,7)

## Frequency table
> counts <- table(a)

## The most frequent and its value
> counts[which.max(counts)]
# 1
# 5

## Or simply the most frequent
> names(counts)[which.max(counts)]
# [1] "1"
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote some personal code to find the mode and a little more (a few years ago. As Ananda showed, it's pretty obvious stuff) :

```
smode<-function(x){
    xtab<-table(x)
    modes<-xtab[max(xtab)==xtab]
    mag<-as.numeric(modes[1]) #in case mult. modes, this is safer
    #themodes<-names(modes)
    themodes<-as.numeric(names(modes))
    mout<-list(themodes=themodes,modeval=mag)
    return(mout)
    }
```

Blah blah copyright blah blah use as you like but don't make money off it.

Comment: Shouldn't you include some error checking for when there are *no* modes? (Not that I should't also with my answer.) Also, how does your last statement about copyright etc work with a "cc-wiki" license. +1 for tidy presentation of the output though.

Comment: There's always a mode, pathologically, since there's always a maximum value in a `table` object.  Granted it's not much use to return a list as long as the input :-).  And I was just joking about copyright--thought the "blah blah" gave that away.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the mode of the data: there are a variety of different options for calculating it. The modeest package has a set of functions for mode estimation, but might be overkill for what you want.

See also:

[Is there a built-in function for finding the mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/standard-library-function-in-r-for-finding-the-mode)

[How to compute conditional Mode in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185392/how-to-compute-conditional-mode-in-r)

Hope that helps

Comment: it returns the message "numeric"

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the function: @Ananda has what looks to be a workable solution. I have added some links to other Stack Overflow threads for the same question.