# Find most common word in a character string

Tags: r, string, sorting, max

I have a character string and need to find the word in the string that occurs most frequently.  I've tried every variation of `max`, `which.max`, `sort`, `order`, and `rank` that I can think of - but can't seem to get the syntax worked out correctly.  I've also tried all of the methods found here: [Calculate frequency of occurrence in an array using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841599/calculate-frequency-of-occurrence-in-an-array-using-r)

Example code:

```
zzz <- c("jan", "feb", "jan", "mar", "mar", "jan", "feb") #random example data
zzz <- paste(zzz, collapse=" ") #make data look like what I'm working with
zzz
# [1] "jan feb jan mar mar jan feb"
```

I this example, "jan" occurs most frequently.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
Freq <- table(unlist(strsplit(zzz," ")))
# > Freq
# feb jan mar 
# 2   3   2 
> Freq[which.max(Freq)]
jan 
  3
```

If you just want the actual word as output,

```
> names(Freq)[which.max(Freq)]
[1] "jan"
```

Comment: You might want to worry about ties too. In this example, the first element of the table (and it's alphabetical, if memory serves), will always be selected in case of a tie.

Comment: What's to worry about? They either exist or they don't.

Answer (score 2):

You could also `factor` the split vector then `tabulate`.

```
f <- factor(strsplit(zzz, " ")[[1]])
levels(f)[which.max(tabulate(f))]
# [1] "jan"
```